# How to run multiple asp.net core MQTT broker on one windows server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mqtt, asp.net-core-2.1

I implemented a MQTT broker by asp.net core 2.2 and want to run it on a Windows server 2016. I am using MQTTnet version 2.8.5 for implementing this broker. This is my startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<MyMqttServer>();
            services.AddMvc();

            var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1886)
                .Build();
            services
                .AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions)
                .AddMqttConnectionHandler()
                .AddConnections()
                .AddMqttTcpServerAdapter();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, MyMqttServer myMqttServer)
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMqttServer(server =>
            {
                server.Started += async (sender, args) => await myMqttServer.RunAsync();
            });
         }
```

and this is my code in Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.ListenAnyIP(1885, l => l.UseMqtt()); // mqtt pipeline
                o.ListenAnyIP(5000); // default http pipeline
            })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

I have two different MQTT broker applications with these settings for MQTT (the other one is set on port 1883 and 1884 in startup) but with different ports. The problem is only one of these MQTT brokers (the broker that works on 1883,1884) works at the same time and the other one does not work. How can I solve that?

Comment: Edit the question to include the error message do you get when the second broker fails to start?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not get any error. the request does not enter to application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to JanEggers in MQTTNET team he helped me to solve the issue. The problem was I have a class myMqttServer that overrides the settings in startup and main class. So I needed to remove those settings and do it in myMqttServer class. You can see the details in this github link.

https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/issues/566

Comment: @kamranamingalvani Hi, in which part you have issue? I ran it as a separate application on server. What exactly you want to do and can you share some code?

Comment: thanks for reply . really i dont know how implement MQTT server ,I have 3 device  and we want manage message from mqtt .please share me how to implement user password  and authentication for devices and how save MQTT message to SqlDatabase . thanks a lot

Comment: @kamranamingalvani First, you need to implement MQTT Broker, this is the server that gets message and advertise that to other clients. You can use this link to implement your broker using C# (https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Server)

Comment: You can also use some clients like mqttBox to test that. In this link (https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Server#validating-mqtt-clients) it shows that how you can validate your clients.

Comment: thank for reply ,username and password should be store in devices ?

Comment: @kamranamingalvani Yes, in most cases you need to keep username and password in client for authentication.